# Show another option box after choosing options from the last one

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to make a filter where when a user choose in the first option box another option box will pop out and so forth. I can do this by submitting the form but what i need is the user need to complete the all selections before submitting. I know that i need a jquery for it or some php code but i can't find and i'm out of idea where to find it.

Here is what i want.

Motor Brand -> Model of Motor -> Motor Parts -> Submit
After that it will filter what is in my database. Can you show me a sample of this. Thx in advance and more power to stackoverflow.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - please be more specific about your problem and provide relevant code to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would work off of `index()` and '.eq()' It will make your js much easier to work with

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxdS4/)

Html

```
<div id ="first">
<select style="display:block">
    <option>Car</option>
    <option>Truck</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id ="second">
<select>
    <option>Mitsubishi</option>
    <option>Honda</option>
</select>
    <select>
    <option>Ford</option>
    <option>Chevy</option>
</select>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(window).load(function(){
     $('#first').find('select').change(function(){
         var show = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
         $('#second select').hide().eq(show).show();    
     });
});
```

Comment: wow this one save my day. (y)

Comment: sir just one question when i try in jsfiddle it works but when i put the code in mine it shows the option box already.

i put the script in head and the css and the option box in the body.

Comment: here is the printscreen sir (https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t31/q71/s720x720/1926146_812709618743321_925859302_o.jpg)

Comment: You will want to wrap the code in a window.load function or put it in the body after the dropdown section

Comment: i tried to put the css and script in the body after the dropdown section still not work. But how to do that in window.load function sir/.

Comment: Keep the css in the head as normal... I'll edit my answer to show you the window.load function

Comment: Edited my answer...Do you have JQuery loaded on the page?

Comment: yes i have jquery sir

Answer (score 0):

You can create three option menus and hide/show then according to the change of the option menu value.

Code sample below I'm giving you a javascript function which will help you.

**toggles visibility:**

```
function showhide(id){

if(document.getElementById(id) .className == "showhidediv_show"){

document.getElementById(id).cl assName="showhidediv_hide"; }else{

document.getElementById(id).cl assName="showhidediv_show"; } }
```

**Individual showhide functions:**

```
function show(id) { document.getElementById(id).cl assName="showhidediv_show"; } function hide(id) {

document.getElementById(id).cl assName="showhidediv_hide"; }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i have found this and i think this one will help me [http://jsfiddle.net/ByfFn/4/]

Comment: Use the above functions on onchange of the dropdown box, thank you.

Comment: my pleasure sir i'll try this one :)